# Problem with Special Price Date in Magento2

Tags: magento2, special-price

I am running Magento 2. The other day I tried for the first time to set a special price, but when I try to set a date I get an error.
After trying some dates I noticed a pattern. 
When I pick a date like 15/01/2018 (15. Jan) I get the error, but when I choose a date that works in both MM:DD:YYYY and DD:MM:YYYY, there is no problem.
My store is in Denmark, and my location and language is as well, but somehow it seems like it only accepts dates in the MM:DD:YYYY-format, even though I can only pick dates from the DD:MM:YYYY-format. So only the dates that fit in both will work...
Is it a wrong setting, or do I have to change some code?
Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you set your locale to any other than `en_US`? 
Try editing the admin user you are using, set the locale for that user to `en_US` and try setting this again.

There is a bug with the datepicker I believe, which causes this problem.

Comment: Thank You! after editing the user settings everything is kind of working